# Why does dropping a nested column in pyspark doesn't work?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, drop

trying to drop a nested column from a dataframe in pyspark doesn't work.

This is the sinppet from my code:

`from pyspark.sql import functions as F
    from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType , BooleanType
    from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

```
#simple filter function
@F.udf(returnType=BooleanType())
def my_filter(x):
    if (x != df_new.a.b) :
       return True
    else :
       return False

#df.filter(my_filter('id', 'category')).show()

def drop_col(df, struct_nm, delete_struct_child_col_nm):
#fields_to_keep = filter(lambda x:  x != delete_struct_child_col_nm, df.select("{}.*".format(struct_nm)).columns)
fields_to_keep = filter(lambda x:  my_filter(x) , df.select("{}.*".format(struct_nm)).columns)
fields_to_keep = list(map(lambda x:  "{}.{}".format(struct_nm, x), fields_to_keep))
return df.withColumn(struct_nm, struct(fields_to_keep))
```

drop_col(df_new, "a", df_new.a.b)`

I used UDF because 
trying the following line didn't work. As this not != symbol doesn't work nor does using tilde

```
#fields_to_keep = filter(lambda x:  x != delete_struct_child_col_nm,     df.select("{}.*".format
```

EDIT:
Someone asked for schema in the comment so i am providing it

```
 root
 |-- a: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- rawEntity: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- entityType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- StoreId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- AppId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Timestamps: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- User: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- b: array (nullable = true)                //trying to drop this
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- KeywordsFull: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Keywords: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Comment: could u provide reproducible sample data for your nested structure? i think for spark2.4 u could use higher order functions to remove

Comment: It's pretty straightforward just dropping a nested column. Its a general function

Comment: can you provide the schema ? using df.printSchema()

Comment: I edited it for you. Thanx